# How to check first 5 chars & last 5 chars of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a string only if its first 5 characters are numeric and last 5 characters are letters:

What I have tried:

```
var userId = "12345abcde";
// Get First and Second Five Characters
var firstFive = userId.substring(0, 5);
var secondFive = userId.substring(5, 10);

// get Global Letter and Nummers
var aStr = /[a-z, A-Z]/g;
var aNum = /[0-9]/g;
var c = userId.match(aNum);

// Try firstFive first...
if (firstFive === c) {
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('nop');
}
```

This alerts `nop`.

Is this because `firstFive` is string and `c` is object? Where is the error in my thinking?

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/xe71dd59/1/

Any tips?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to check whether the first five chars are numbers and last five chars are characters..?

Comment: You can use Split or match function for doing this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
/^[0-9]{5}.*[a-z]{5}$/i.test("12345abcde")
```

Answer (score 1):

`match` returns an array of results or NULL if none were found.

```
var c = firstFive.match(aNum);
if(c!=null)
{
    if(c.length==5)
    {
        alert("Yes");
    }
}
```

Comment: the regex is not testing for `start with number`

Comment: That's because he's also used his regex on `userId` instead of his pre-made substring `firstFive`. Which is above my fix, but I'll edit it into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this way:

```js
var userId = "12345abcde";

var result = /^[0-9]{5}.*[a-z]{5}$/i.test(userId);

if (result) {
    alert('yes');
}else{
    alert('nop');
}
```